# Branch (React-native) deeplinking is not working in FB messenger (Android)

Tags: branch, deep-linking, facebook-messenger, branch.io

I am using Branch.io to send users their credentials in my app. Since the app is not live yet, i am testing with everything on "live" in the Branch settings.

If I create a link from the app and send it via Slack or email, with the app installed then the app opens but if I share the link with Facebook messenger then the fallback url is used. EDIT:The fallback is the expected behavior on iOS, but i am working on Android.

I did find [this](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/issues/382) which (1) is not very promising (2) is old (3) is not exactly the same situation since the links do work for me.

Comment: Do you have any code to look into ?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the link from the Facebook Messenger app, then redirecting to the Fallback URL is the expected link behavior:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#expected-link-behavior

Per the docs, you can still open the app using URI schemes or a Deepview.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that this was on Android, not on iOS.